# How stop moving the view when entering walk mode?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, navigation

When I enter walk mode, I want the view to stay in the same position. Here's what the documentation says:

> On activation the mouse pointer will move at the center of the view, and a cross marker will appear…

I don't want the mouse pointer to move. I found nothing in settings to adjust this behavior

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the issue with the help of dann#6226 (Discord)

> try to change the shortcut, I suspect it might be doing two things at once.

> does it do this if you use the menu to enter and exit?

I was using middle mouse, and multiple actions where having the bind on this button. Changing it to another key and making sure to not be used by other actions too, fixed the problem